# PowerBuilder - Objects in nested report

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

just want to ask, in PowerBuilder,  how to modify the properties of the object inside the nested report. The main DataWindow is not a composite DataWindow, it's only a tabular. I'm having a hard time modifying the Visible property of 2 column inside the nested report.

Hope to hear an answer here soon...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To do this for all instances (i.e. all rows) of the nested report, use GetChild() and do the Modify() against the DataWindowChild that is returned in the reference argument.

Good luck,

Terry.